# UserDefaults not persisting data in TextView

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Edit: I noticed I am using different keys (was playing with the code), but even if they are same, I get similar results.

I have looked all over StackOverflow but not found a solution for this. I have a textview on a second view in my storyboard, and I need it to persist the data without any button press. I should go to the view, see the text and when the app backgrounds (or view disappears), it should persist that data.

I've got it working to the point the text appears on the second view (via a segue), but it doesn't update with new text which is appended via the loop and doesn't persist the data. Also, if I tap a "clear" button to clear the view, it clears the textview but as soon as I go back to the view, the data comes back.

In essence it's stuck on saving just one line of my textview and nothing more. Any help would be appriciated as I am very new to Xcode. (Latest Xcode with Swift 3).

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CalcViewController: UIViewController {
    var tape = Array<String>()

    @IBOutlet weak var calcTape: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for eachNewLineInTape in tape {
            calcTape.text = calcTape.text + eachNewLineInTape + "\r\n"
        }

        let sel:Selector = #selector(self.appMovedToBackground)
        let notificationCentre = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCentre.addObserver(self, selector: sel, name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

        if let userDataNew:AnyObject = defaults.object(forKey: "userDataNew") as AnyObject?{
            calcTape.text = (userDataNew as! Array).first

            print("SAVED")
        }
        else {
            print("not saved")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func clearAll(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // if the tape is not empty...
        if (calcTape.text != ""){
            // empty it (set to empty string)
            calcTape.text = ""
            let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
            UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: bundleIdentifier!)
        } else {
            // otherwise, it was already empty, so display a message
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Nothing to clear", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func appMovedToBackground(){
        print("App moved to background")
        let myText = calcTape.text
        UserDefaults.standard.set(myText, forKey: "savedStringKey")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        print("saved")
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you used the same key for saving and loading the data to/from user defaults. Better yet, declare a constant and use it in both places.

Comment: You are using two different keys; `userDataNew` and `savedStringKey`.  One is saving an array and the other has a string. And user defaults is not meant to be a data store.  Yes, learn how to use user defaults.  No, don't learn how to use it as a data store.  Use plists or Core Data or Realm or ...

Comment: @rmaddy even if they are same, I get similar results.

Comment: @Paulw11 even if they are same, I get similar results.

Comment: Are you sure appMovedToBackground is being fired?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you tested and verified that `appMovedToBackground` is called.

First, as it was mentioned in the comments, you need to use the same key.

Then, in your saving code:

```
let myText = calcTape.text
UserDefaults.standard.set(myText, forKey: "savedStringKey")
```

`myText` has `String` type, so it should store it as is.

But then in your loading code, you are doing something really strange. This line should succeed and userDataNew will have your saved string.

```
if let userDataNew:AnyObject = defaults.object(forKey: "userDataNew") as AnyObject?{
```

But after that you are force casting it to `Array`. Your program must crash straight away:

```
calcTape.text = (userDataNew as! Array).first
```

The correct way for loading should be just:

```
calcTape.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "savedStringKey")
```

Slightly off topic, but a few improvements in your code:
Instead of this:

```
for eachNewLineInTape in tape {
   calcTape.text = calcTape.text + eachNewLineInTape + "\r\n"
}
```

you could write:

```
calcTape.text = tape.joined(separator: "\r\n")
```

Comment: Working OK, and its made me change "if let userDataNew:AnyObject...." to "if let _:AnyObject = defaults....". When I go back to my first view to add more data/text to that textview, it is not added - it only remembers the first entry. And when I quit the app from multitasking, it is not recovering the data properly. Any advice here?

Comment: Also changed all keys to "savedStringKey"

Comment: If you kill your app, then the notification definitely will not be called. Probably, knowing the specific use case, it would be better to find certain events to detect when the input should be saved. Regarding loading, you can move your loading code to `viewWillAppear` if you are coming back to it instead of reinstantiating the VC.

Comment: You could also save date in `viewWillDisappear`, or if you have multiple fields on the view, then you can add action to `Editing Did End` or add a delegate and save it from `textViewDidEndEditing`

Comment: tried both, still all not working. The calcTape.text is only remembering the first thing that goes into it, and new entries are not saved.

Comment: Just put breakpoint and check whether it tries to save. It can't be that it only stores the first value, I use it all the time and it's not how it works

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering my own question (not sure how else to do it and make it clear), but this is how the code looks now:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewControllerTwo: UIViewController {

var tape = Array<String>()

@IBOutlet weak var calcTape: UITextView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    calcTape.text = tape.joined(separator: "\r\n")

    let sel:Selector = #selector(self.appMovedToBackground)
    let notificationCentre = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCentre.addObserver(self, selector: sel, name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if let _:AnyObject = defaults.object(forKey: "savedStringKey") as AnyObject?{

        calcTape.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "savedStringKey")

        print("SAVED")
    }
    else {
        print("not saved")
    }


}

@IBAction func clearAll(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // if the tape is not empty...
    if (calcTape.text != ""){

        // empty it (set to empty string)

        calcTape.text = ""
        let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
        UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: bundleIdentifier!)


    } else {
        // otherwise, it was already empty, so display a message
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Nothing to clear", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


func appMovedToBackground(){
    print("App moved to background")
    let myText = calcTape.text
    UserDefaults.standard.set(myText, forKey: "savedStringKey")
    print("saved in bg")
    }
}
```